# Include WSDL in OSGi bundle

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, osgi, cxf

I've got a bundle which needs to communicate with a web service. The client was generated using Apache CXF, the WSDL of the web service is a local file, because the target system doesn't host the WSDL.

How can I integrate the WSDL into my OSGi bundle? Currently the web service client points to a file path of the WSDL which is pretty unuseful for deployment. Is there any way I can put the WSDL into the OSGi bundle? I tought about the resources folder, but there is none in my OSGi bundle.

This is the relevant part of the Java class:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "WebService", targetNamespace = "http://company.com/target/namespace", wsdlLocation = "/tmp/WebService.wsdl")
public class WebService
```

After trying out [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_client) article, my code looks like this:

```
static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url =  XI07D2B3188DService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("WebService.wsdl");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        XI07D2B3188DSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        XI07D2B3188DSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }
```

The error with the not found WSDL is now gone, but I've got a new error:

```
500 XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

This is the beginning of my WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="SI_PARTNER_OPENTIMES_OA" targetNamespace="http://company.ch/xi/partnernet/partner" xmlns:p1="http://company.ch/xi/partnernet/partner" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:documentation />
  <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true" />
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_SI_PARTNER_OPENTIMES_OA" />
```

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae) question on SO. I tried changing it to UTF-16 but that didn't help. I also copied the content within Eclipse into a new file, but I've still got this error. Any idea?

Comment: See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_client) for a JAX-WS example loading the WSDL from the classpath in an unmanaged client.

Comment: @McDowell While this works as normal Java Code, I have to specify my WSDL location as parameter of an annotation (updated the question for clarification). I don't know if and how I can reference the file from there.

Comment: _wsdlLocation_ is only a logical path and can be ignored at runtime. If you have a specific exception in your code state what that is and what exception you are getting. Show some code.

Comment: @McDowell I now tried your link. See updated question for more details. I can post you the whole web service code, but it's autogenerated and actually looks pretty ugly.

Comment: _Content is not allowed in prolog_ can be caused by a number of reasons but the `encoding="UTF-8"` declaration needs to match the [actual encoding](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/java-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog.html) of the document. This is a separate issue to any OSGi-related problems.

Comment: @McDowell I have checked the document with a hex editor, and the hex values of the characters do match the UTF-8 table - doesn't look like a formatting problem to me :\. Also I can't see any "invisible" signs using the hex-editor, the XML seems fine (it works as it is when referenced from disk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't get it to include the WSDL into the classpath, I did it another way. I've created a directory for my application under /etc/ in CRXDE (I'm using Adobe CQ5) and put the WSDL file in there. Then I've just pointed my web service client to the http address of the directory (which would've been `http://localhost:4503/etc/projectname/webservice.wsdl`).

I'm still open for a cleaner approach (this will only work on Publish instances, since on a author instance it'll require login credentials), but so far it does what I need and allows me to deploy everything at once.