# Liferay SAXException when starting OSGi module httpclient-osgi-4.5.3.jar

Tags: liferay, osgi, apache-httpclient-4.x, equinox, liferay-7

In Liferay 7 (DXP sp4) I need to install these OSGi modules:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.3
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.4.6

So, I download them, put `httpcore-osgi-4.4.6.jar` in `deploy/`, it starts successfully as seen in Gogo Shell. Then I put `httpclient-osgi-4.5.3.jar` in `deploy/`, and…

```
ERROR [fileinstall-/home/nico/liferay/osgi/modules][org_eclipse_equinox_metatype:97] Unable to parse metadata XML at "bundleentry://540.fwk517213600/OSGI-INF/metatype/metatype.properties" for bundle ID "540" with symbolic name "org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient". 
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Fatal Error: URI=null Line=1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.metatype.impl.DataParser$MyErrorHandler.fatalError(DataParser.java:856)
```

I don't know what this `metatype.properties` file is nor why Equinox tries to parse it as XML.

Is this JAR not a standard OSGi module?
Or does Liferay require a somehow different OSGi module?
Is it a problem with my configuration? (freshly installed)
Should I just ignore this ERROR?

The most incredible is that nonetheless the module gets started:

```
INFO  [fileinstall-/home/nico/liferay/osgi/modules][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.3 [540]
```

Comment: There are several reports on this error, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae. That doesn't help with this downloaded component, but it seems that filing an issue regarding packaging seems reasonable. There's nothing Liferay-specific that happens during the deploy process, it's being deployed by equinox as you can see in the stacktrace.

Comment: @OlafKock: I filed an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1862 thanks always for the feedback!

Comment: @OlafKock: The issue was closed as `Won't fix`, they think the problem is either with the OSGi container or Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin.

Comment: I know this is an old one now, we had this error message. If you update the liferay 7.2 you can use JDK11 which has a native http client instead.

Comment: Ticket open at Equinox project https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551228

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be rooted at the [MetaTypeProviderImpl.java:91](https://github.com/eclipse/rt.equinox.bundles/blob/a05e887ec911edc1bdde68182cf6a2dbad65915e/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.metatype/src/org/eclipse/equinox/metatype/impl/MetaTypeProviderImpl.java#L91). The class is loading all (*) metadata files and reading them as a XML.