# Saxon: Can't open XML with schema in .NET, works fine in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, schema, saxon

I am trying to create a Saxon XPathCompiler. I have the same code in Java & .NET, each calling the appropriate Saxon library. The code is:

```
protected void ctor(InputStream xmlData, InputStream schemaFile, boolean preserveWhiteSpace) throws SAXException, SchemaException, SaxonApiException {
    this.rootNode = makeDataSourceNode(null);
    XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

    InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(xmlData);
    SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(reader, xmlSource);
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(schemaFile);
    Configuration config = createEnterpriseConfiguration();
    config.addSchemaSource(schemaSource);
    // ...
```

In the case of .NET the InputStreams are a class that wrpas a .NET Stream and makes it a Java InputStream. For Java the above code works fine. But in .NET, the last line, config.addSchemaSource(schemaSource) throws:

> $exception    {"Content is not allowed in
>   prolog."} org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

In both Java & .NET it works fine if there is no schema.

The files it is using are http://www.thielen.com/test/SouthWind.xml & http://www.thielen.com/test/SouthWind.xsd

[It does not appear to be any of the issues in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae) And if that was the issue, shouldn't both Java and .NET have the same problem.

I'm thinking maybe it's the wrapper around the .NET Stream to make it a Java InputStream, but we use that class everywhere without any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

The "content is not allowed in Prolog" exception is absolutely infuriating - if only it told you what the bytes are that it is complaining about! One diagnostic technique is to display the initial bytes delivered by the InputStream: do a few calls on

```
System.err.println(schemaFile.next())
```

My first guess as to the cause would be something to do with byte order marks, but rather than speculate, I would focus on diagnostics to see what the parser is seeing in that InputStream that it doesn't like.

Comment: I fixed it by explicitly setting both files to utf-8 encoding (previously the xml file had no spec and the xsd was utf-16). But encoding should not make a difference...

Comment: Hey, you wrote Saxon. Can't you give us more info on the exception? thanks - dave

Comment: Saxon calls an external XML parser to do the parsing: by default it uses the XML parser in the JDK. Sometimes you can get better diagnostics by configuring Saxon to use a different parser (but Xerces has pretty well cornered the market these days).

Comment: Oh... Ok, now this all makes sense.