# Execute Java petstore 1.1.2 using JDK1.8

Tags: jakarta-ee, legacy-app

I need to run JPS 1.1.2 (exactly that version) on a server (JBoss, Tomcat, Glassfish,...) using Java SE 7+. 
I have managed to deploy it on a Glassfish server (running with JDK1.8). I had to modify the SQL code to populate the database. But, i can't enter the petstore. I got this from server logs :

```
[Fatal Error] :1:41: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

then this :

```
    WebModule[/estore]StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.ScreenFlowXmlDAO.getTagValue(ScreenFlowXmlDAO.java:379)
    at com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.ScreenFlowXmlDAO.getScreens(ScreenFlowXmlDAO.java:173)
    at com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.ScreenFlowXmlDAO.loadScreenDefinitions(ScreenFlowXmlDAO.java:110)
    at com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.ScreenFlowManager.init(ScreenFlowManager.java:65)
    at com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.MainServlet.getScreenFlowManager(MainServlet.java:145)
    at com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I followed the last tag used that caused the error, it was "template"
has anyone succeded to run JPS 1.1.2, i would appreciate the help.

Comment: It sounds like the XML file has spaces in it or a new line, that error in my experience can be indicative of extra white space.

Comment: I found nothing wrong with the XML file !

Comment: Can you double check it again after reading the answers here? [content is not allowed in prolog when parsing perfectly valid xml on gae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae)

Comment: It also might be worth it to try the 2.0 version, I'd try and run it as is without making any modifications [JPS 2.0](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/petstore-137013.html)