# Manifest merger exception: SAXParseException

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

We have a project that uses different product flavors and product types.  When I select a particular flavor, this error is generated:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processSomeFlavorDebugManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Here is what I have tried:

- ran the task with -info, -debug, -scan, not very helpful.
- reviewed the two manifest files to ensure there are no weird characters or spaces in the prolog
- cleaned project
- rebuilt project
- invalidated cache and restart
- deleted AndroidSDK and Android Studio (also AndroidStudio3.5 directories in ~/Library/...)

Weird thing is, this exact branch builds perfectly fine for others.  Did anyone encounter this before?

Comment: it might be already answered here checkout  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae

Comment: I don't think it’s the manifest itself since it builds on other machines and build server.

Comment: _"ran the task with -info, -debug, -scan, not very helpful"_ Not very, but you got something? Some extra info might help...

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Comment: please add your manifest code also @TakeshiKaga

Comment: This was fixed by upgrading to the latest Gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown from "**manifest merger**" inside of android gradle plugin.

Try to add this line to the `manifest` node in your main manifest file.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

**Note**: You need to use the same android support library version. You need to use support library 28.0.0 version.

I hope it'll help you..!

Answer (score 0):

check that your manifest have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="yourpacagename">
```

for more info check this [issue](https://github.com/Vigi0303/fat-aar-plugin/issues/2)  on github

also all your xml files should have this line at the beginning

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```