# Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'

Tags: java, spring, file

Hi Im making a big MVC project and now I'm trying to implement a logging functionallity through .xml file. I've triple checked the heading for typos and tried using differend encodings but nothing worked. I've added appenders for RollingFile and ConsoleAppender.I want to make a log containing name,date and level.I think thats all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="logs/app.log"/>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 5KB -->
            <maxFileSize>5KB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20KB,
                it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>20KB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 60 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>




    <logger name="com.dailycodebuffer" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="EMAIL"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.dailycodebuffer" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="com.dailycodebuffer" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

the error im getting

```
 Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback.xml
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:186)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at com.myfirm.CarDealer.CarDealerApplication.main(CarDealerApplication.java:10)
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Problem parsing XML document. See previously reported errors.
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:71)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.populateSaxEventRecorder(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:178)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:159)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:237)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/gitlabProjects/project1/car_dealer/cardealer/target/classes/logback.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1251)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:326)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:64)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by deleting the whole xml version and encoding

Answer (score 0):

It looks You have space at start of logback.xml
error: `lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; Content is not allowed in prolog.`
remove it

I added space in my config and inteliJ highlighted it as error
[image: inteliJ error hint]

, also running app returns similar problem as Yours

Comment: this happened when i parsed the code in stackoverflow

Comment: it might be encoding problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae , maybe it has encoding `UTF-8 BOM`

Comment: i tried with the different encodings but the best one i got was with UTF-16 which got me ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.LoggerConverter@558bdf1f - failed to parse integer string [1.] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1." which is the same situation Im in right now

Comment: If You are changing encoding check if file encoding is equal to encoding specified in first line

Comment: also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog