# "[Fatal Error] ... Content is not allowed in prolog" Getting this error out od nowhere

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

Flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2846], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I've tried `flutter clean`, I've tried deleting my gradle folder(not .gradle), `flutter downgrade`

My flutter version

```
Flutter 3.16.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision db7ef5bf9f (5 weeks ago) • 2023-11-15 11:25:44 -0800
Engine • revision 74d16627b9
Tools • Dart 3.2.0 • DevTools 2.28.2
```

This is part of the error. The complete thing is too long to post on stack. I don't know what's causing it. Please help

```
[Fatal Error] jaxb-bom-ext-2.3.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] slf4j-api-1.7.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] dagger-2.28.3.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] error_prone_annotations-2.3.1.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] jose4j-0.7.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] jdom2-2.0.6.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] error_prone_annotations-2.4.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] perfmark-api-0.23.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] annotations-4.1.1.4.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] grpc-api-1.39.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] animal-sniffer-annotations-1.19.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] netty-codec-http2-4.1.52.Final.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] netty-handler-proxy-4.1.52.Final.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] proto-google-common-protos-2.0.1.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] jsr305-3.0.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] grpc-protobuf-lite-1.39.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] json-20180813.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] checker-qual-2.5.8.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] manifest-merger-30.4.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] apksig-7.4.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] javawriter-2.5.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] signflinger-7.4.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] tracker-30.4.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] zipflinger-7.4.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] apkzlib-7.4.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-native-utils-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-util-io-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] jna-5.6.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-daemon-client-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-build-common-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-scripting-jvm-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-scripting-common-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-1.7.22.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] checker-qual-3.5.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] failureaccess-1.0.1.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] j2objc-annotations-1.3.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] xml-apis-1.4.01.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.4.2
      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.6.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.6.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.5.6/httpcomponents-client-4.5.6.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-parent:10.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-parent:10.
                           > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-parent/10/httpcomponents-parent-10.pom
                              > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:18.
                                 > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:18.
                                    > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/18/apache-18.pom
                                       > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.4.2
      > Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.pom
            > Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-runtime-parent:2.3.2.
               > Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-runtime-parent:2.3.2.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-runtime-parent/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-parent-2.3.2.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-parent:2.3.2.
                        > Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-parent:2.3.2.
                           > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-parent/2.3.2/jaxb-parent-2.3.2.pom
                              > Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-bom-ext:2.3.2.
                                 > Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-bom-ext:2.3.2.
                                    > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-bom-ext/2.3.2/jaxb-bom-ext-2.3.2.pom
                                       > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2
      > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom  
            > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.4.2
      > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:48.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:48.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/48/commons-parent-48.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:21.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache:apache:21.
                           > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/21/apache-21.pom    
                              > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.4.2
      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:4.4.13.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:4.4.13.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.4.13/httpcomponents-core-4.4.13.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-parent:11.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-parent:11.
                           > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-parent/11/httpcomponents-parent-11.pom
                              > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.4.2
      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.13.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.13.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.5.13/httpcomponents-client-4.5.13.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-parent:11.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-parent:11.
                           > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-parent/11/httpcomponents-parent-11.pom
                              > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.4
      > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.2/auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.4.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.4
      > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.4.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.4.0/error_prone_annotations-2.4.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.4
      > Could not resolve com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/dagger/dagger/2.28.3/dagger-2.28.3.pom       
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.7.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.4
      > Could not resolve org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.7.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bitbucket/b_c/jose4j/0.7.0/jose4j-0.7.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.4
      > Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.22.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta10     
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta10      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.22.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.22/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.22.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta10      > Could not resolve org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/jdom2-2.0.6.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.4.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.17.2
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 > com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre
      > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.4.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.4.0/error_prone_annotations-2.4.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-api:1.39.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > io.grpc:grpc-core:1.39.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.39.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.39.0
      > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-api:1.39.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/1.39.0/grpc-api-1.39.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android:annotations:4.1.1.4.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > io.grpc:grpc-core:1.39.0
      > Could not resolve com.google.android:annotations:4.1.1.4.
         > Could not parse POM
```

Pubspec.yaml

```
name: nle_print
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.3 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  file_picker: ^5.3.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.8
  firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  rive: ^0.11.4
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^21.2.10
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.3.2
  path: ^1.8.2
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  http: ^0.13.6
  cloud_firestore: ^4.12.2
  read_pdf_text: ^0.2.1
  intl: ^0.18.1
  firebase_app_check: ^0.2.1+3
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.3
  provider: ^6.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
  flutter_local_notifications: ^16.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/RiveAssets/
    - assets/images/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf
    - family: Intel
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
    - family: Akira
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Akira-Expanded.otf
          weight: 500
    - family: Monument
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/MonumentExtended-Regular.otf
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/MonumentExtended-Ultrabold.otf
          weight: 800
  #
```

I've tried `flutter clean`, I've tried deleting my gradle folder(not .gradle), `flutter downgrade`
None worked
I'm using VS Code and Windows 10. My project is an android app

Comment: I have seen that error returned by xml parsers see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae for an example, the first line in the trace contains jaxb-bom-ext which is a java xml package, suggest delete any ,flutter, .dart  cache directories, then upgrade to the latest possible java version