encountering Error: Content is not allowed in prolog with spring boot and apache camel, when transforming
I am writing a springboot application to convert SOAP to REST by using apache camel -
private String transformSoapToRest(String soapRequest) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        soapRequest = soapRequest.trim();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(soapRequest)));

        String requestData = document.getElementsByTagName("arg0").item(0).getTextContent();

        return "{ \"requestData\": \"" + requestData + "\" }";
    }

    private String transformRestToSoap(String restResponse) {
        restResponse = restResponse.trim();

        String soapResponse = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                "<soap:Body>" +
                "<ser:processRequestResponse xmlns:ser=\"http://Service.project.Soap2Rest.com/\">" +
                "<return>" + restResponse + "</return>" +
                "</ser:processRequestResponse>" +
                "</soap:Body>" +
                "</soap:Envelope>";
        return soapResponse;
    }

this is my logic for the same and this is my route -
 from("cxf:bean:soapCxfEndpoint")
                .log("Received SOAP request: ${body}")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    String soapRequest = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).trim();
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(soapRequest);
                    String restResponse = transformSoapToRest(soapRequest);
                    log.info("Transformed rest request: " + soapRequest);
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(restResponse.trim());
                })
                .log("Transformed to REST request: ${body}")
                .to("http://localhost:8080/rest/api")
                .log("Received REST response: ${body}")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    String restRequest = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).trim();
                    String soapResponse = transformRestToSoap(restRequest);
                    log.info("Transformed rest request: " + restRequest);
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(soapResponse.trim());
                })
                .log("Transformed to SOAP response: ${body}")
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/xml"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                .to("direct:log");

        from("direct:log")
                .log("Log entry: ${body}");
    }

i entered the following on my postman with the url http://localhost:8080/services/soap and the follwing xml -
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://Service.project.Soap2Rest.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:processRequest>
         <arg0>Sample Request</arg0>
      </ser:processRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

and i am continuously getting the error -
2024-07-17T18:24:05.447+05:30 DEBUG 21736 --- [project] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: DEA1ACD506C7924-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: DEA1ACD506C7924-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
2024-07-17T18:24:05.449+05:30  INFO 21736 --- [project] [nio-8080-exec-1] route1                                   : Exception occurred: Content is not allowed in prolog.

I have made sure that there are no trailing whitespaces in the xml, rechecked everything.
Even used tools like a text editor that can show non-printable characters, still no solution.
Now I am at my wits end about what the problem might be, please help.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae

i did, not working for me

There are a lot of different solution to the issue at the link.  Did you look at all of them?
